# ASP .net unit test controller using MOLES

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, moles

How can i unit test a controller that contains HttpConext using moles framework?
    My Code for the controller is

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
             MyRepositoryClass myRepo = new MyRepositoryClass (System.Web.HttpContext.Current);
             string fs = ipser.GetCityName();
             return View();
        }

My code for the controller in unit test project is
public class MyClassTest
{

   [TestMethod]
   [HostType("Moles")]
    public void Index_Test()
    {
         string originalViewName="Index";
         MyController myContl = new MyController ();
         var result =myContl.Index() as ViewResult;
         Assert.IsNotNull(result, "Should return a view");
         Assert.AreEqual(originalViewName, result.ViewName, "View name should have been {0}", originalViewName);
    }
```

How should i test my controller using moles framework?

Comment: This might help you: http://blog.dotnetwiki.org/2010/08/24/NewUnitTestingAspNETApplicationsWithPexAndMolesTutorial.aspx

Comment: Just for your information 0 Not sure you are using Unity as your IOC container, and Moq as your isolation framework, you can use the automocking to easily stub out the context. http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=767

Answer (score 1):

The quick answer is don't use Moles, but instead remove your dependency on the static HttpContext object.

If you use HttpContextBase (in System.Web.Abstractions in .NET 4.0) instead of HttpContext you'll be able to supply a fake HttpContext in your unit tests.  You will need to use an IoC container in your MVC app and ensure you map HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current) to HttpContextBase in when configuring the IoC container.

There's plenty of info on how this is done on the web.  Just Google for HttpContextBase, HttpContextWrapper and MVC and I'm sure you'll find plenty of example code and explanations to help you.

Comment: Just curious, any reason you say "don't use Moles"? Is that in general or for this particular case?

Comment: Sorry overlooked, yes it is for this particular case :)